# How to populate selectbox based on selection of another selectbox using Spring 4 Boot + ThymeLeaf+Hibernate

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am creating a registration form where i am have to create three select box. First selectbox contains all the countries, based on selection the state select box become visible and only state available in particular selected country will be display. there is also city selectbox too, where by default city dropdown will not display until state been selected and based on selection only cities belongs to particular state selected in state selectbox will be displayed.

I am able to generate all select box, but how to filter based on selection, i really don't know.

**Effort:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:text="#{register.label.country}" `class="col-md-4 control-label">Country:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{address.country}">
            <option value="-1">--- Select Country ---</option>
            <option th:each="country : *{countries}" th:value="${country.configId}" th:text="${country.configName}"></option>
        </select>
        <strong th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address.country')}" th:errors="*{address.country}">Country Error</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:text="#{register.label.state}" class="col-md-4 control-label">State:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{address.state}">
            <option value="-1">--- Select State ---</option>
            <option th:each="state : *{states.?[parentid = 1]}" th:value="${state.configId}" th:text="${state.configName}"></option>
        </select>
        <strong th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address.state')}" th:errors="*{address.state}">Country Error</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:text="#{register.label.city}" class="col-md-4 control-label">City:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{address.city}">
            <option value="-1">--- Select City ---</option>
            <option th:each="city : *{cities}" th:value="${city.configId}" th:text="${city.configName}"></option>
        </select>
        <strong th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address.city')}" th:errors="*{address.city}">Country Error</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to generate all the selectbox, but i really don't know how to generate based on selection in thymeleaf with Spring boot.

Please help me. I know i can do this by using jquery ajax, but i want to avoid, i am thing is it possible with thymeleaf itself or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is a server-side web template engine.
Once it is rendered, and is displayed to client, Thymeleaf is no longer there.
The only way to handle it is through javascript; or by sending a new request to render new filtered options.